# Problems With /replaceitem Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on the KitPVP part of my server again. I'm trashing the part about buying the kits. All of them will be free. I'm trying to use /replaceitem to get the players their kits, but I have a few problems. I'm trying to get a leather tunic on the user which is dyed, named "Brute's Body", and enchanted. This is what I've tried:

```
replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.chest leather_chestplate 1 0 {display:{color:7514398,Name:Brute's Body},ench:[{id:0,lvl:4},{id:34,lvl:10}]}
```

When I try this, it says it replaced that slot with "leather chestplate" but then it doesn't. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you take it off first? Did you try a shorter command first? Otherwise any part of this could be the problem.

Comment: Um... no this is the only command I could think of that would work

Comment: I think it has something to do with the name, though. It worked without the name, but when I added it, it didn't

Comment: Very good, that's step 1 of debugging. Step 2, try the name alone and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, I did that. It didn't work with the name alone, either.

Comment: Then go deeper: Does the name without the colour work? Does the colour with a different name work? Does a different armour piece in a different slot work?

Comment: Name without color = does not work.

Comment: Color with different name = does not work

Comment: I tried everything I could think of and everything u suggested. None of them work. It also doesn't have an output. It says the same thing it said the first time I tried it. "Replaced slot.armor.chest with * Leather Tunic". Something like that. It's like it's not even activating

Comment: This command is a chain command block in a small chain of command blocks BTW. Could it have something to do with that?

Comment: I don't know. Try it. I'll also try some things now.

Comment: The command works fine for me in 1.12 with the added quotation marks from IronAnvil's answer. In 1.13 the slot is called "`armor.chest`", the NBT comes right after the item name (without a space) and the data value is not needed anymore. In both versions it successfully puts the item in the slot, no matter if something's there already, it has the colour, the name and the enchantments. Also, I just noticed that `color` is inside the `display` tag. That works, but it's weird. Maybe that' a bug, but irrelevant for you, because the command does work.Are you sure you're trying the same in the game?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I figured it out. It was the command block, not the command.

Comment: Wait, your hexadecimal color is 7 digits, or is it RGB?

Answer (score 1):

The Name tag needs to be contained within quotation marks:

```
replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.chest leather_chestplate 1 0 {display:{color:7514398,Name:"Brute's Body"},ench:[{id:0,lvl:4},{id:34,lvl:10}]}
```

Comment: I just tried that, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Could the problem be that the command block chain isn't set up right? It is: block with button on front = top, normal command block facing down = middle, chain command block facing down = bottom. The chain one is the one with the "Brute's Body" command.

Comment: The command, as I posted, works properly for me.  Type the command into chat to run manually to test it.  This will tell you if it's the command blocks.  If you have a "normal" command block (which I took to mean Impulse), in between the first command block and a chain block, it is definitely wrong if you are expecting [chained execution](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Command_Block#Chained_execution).

Comment: @hakalo Is the command block maybe set to "always active" or the chain command block to "requires redstone"? Also, you should try commands in chat first to rule out such problems.

Comment: Yeah, ok. I put the command into chat and it worked. This means it has to have something to do with the command blocks

Answer (score -1):

Execute this in chat, but make sure your in 1.12:

`/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.chest leather_chestplate 1 0 {display:{color:7514398,Name:"Brute's Body"},ench:[{id:0,lvl:4},{id:34,lvl:10}]}`